# Sublime Text doesn't open files from PcManFM

Tags: xubuntu, sublime-text, pcmanfm

Do you have any clue what might me a problem when opening text file from PcManFM file manager by Sublime Text 3? Nothing happens then. In Thunar it works just like it should work.

Do you have idea where could a problem be? I have opened a sublime_text.desktop:

[Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 Type=Application Name=Sublime Text GenericName=Text Editor Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F Terminal=false MimeType=text/plain; Icon=sublime-text Categories=TextEditor;Development; StartupNotify=true Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window] Name=New Window Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document] Name=New File Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file OnlyShowIn=Unity;

I am using Xubuntu, 13.10.

Thank you very much for any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved it out. I opened a file through command line: "subl %f" and saved this "shortcut" as a default programme for that file extension. It just works! :-)